# SQL Server: how to include count in the select query with where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
id     out    flag
---   ---     ---
 1     0       1
 1     1       0
 1     4       0
 2     0       1
 2     2       0
 2     2       0
 3     0       1
 3     2       0
 3     1       0
 3     4       0
```

I want to count the number of rows with out=(0, 2, or 4) and later display rows where flag = 1

Basically:
select id, count(where out IN(0,2,4)) as cnt where flag = 1

My desired output:

```
 id  cnt
---  ----
 1     2
 2     3
 3     3
```

This query works as expected but only when I don't have "where flag = 1":

```
select id,sum(case when out in (0,2,4) then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) as cnt
from tablename
```

Is there a way for me to calculate sum() of something first and store it in a column, and later filter out rows using where clause? currently what's happening is that rows are being filtered out first and later sum(...) is calculated.

Any way I can rectify this?

Comment: should the output for id =1 be 2?

Comment: I agree, id=1 should be have a count of 2

Comment: Just updated! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please update the post to reflect your real need or open a new post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to sum only rows for an id when they have specified values for the `out` column.

```
select id,sum(case when out in (0,2,4) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from tablename
group by id
```

Edit: To include other columns when summing, use the `sum` window function.

```
select * from (select id,flag
               ,sum(case when out in (0,2,4) then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) as cnt
               --include other columns as required
               from tablename
              ) x 
where flag=1
```

Comment: I'm getting a "id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error. I have multiple columns in my select statement and including all of them in GROUP BY would make it very complicated. is there a way i can use your query without using groupby for every column in the select statement?

Comment: This is working as expected! There's just one more thing - my query also has a where clause in it which is filtering out result from the table. Is there a way I can find the sum() first and later have the where clause filter the rows? Is creating another select query and inner joining it my only solution?

Comment: please post all your requirements in the question itself.

Comment: I just edited my post. can you please check? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select      id,count(*) as cnt
from        tablename
where       out in (0,2,4)
group by    id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do count for `0,2,4` OUT. And then filter them with a `Inner Join` or using Correlated subquery

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ID  INT,   OUT_VALUE INT,    FLAG INT)

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,  0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  1,  1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  1,  4, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,  0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,  2, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,  2, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  3,  0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  3,  2, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  3,  1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  3,  4, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  4,  4, 0
```

Now do select like below

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT T1.ID,COUNT(1) C
FROM #TAB T1
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #TAB WHERE FLAG = 1
)FLAGS ON T1.ID = FLAGS.ID
 WHERE T1.OUT_VALUE IN (0,2,4)
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

**Correlated Sub-query**

```
SELECT ID, C  FROM (
SELECT T1.ID
,COUNT(1) C
,(
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM #TAB T2
        WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
            AND T2.FLAG = 1
        ) FLAG


FROM #TAB T1 WHERE T1.OUT_VALUE IN (0,2,4)
GROUP BY T1.ID

)A
WHERE A.FLAG IS NOT NULL
```

The result will be

```
+----+---+
| ID | C |
+----+---+
|  1 | 2 |
|  2 | 3 |
|  3 | 3 |
+----+---+
```